# Marionette composite View appendHtml not triggered

Tags: marionette

Consider the following Marionette composite View. Does anyone know wy appendHtml event does Not fire:

```
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#node-template",
tagName: "ul",

initialize: function(){

    this.collection = this.model.nodes;
},

appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){

    alert('appendHtml triggered');
    collectionView.$("li:first").append(itemView.el);
}
});
```

look at the alert('appendHtml triggered'); Why does it not fire?
Has that been removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-attachhtml). Depending on the version of Marionette you are using. Use attachHtml()

Comment: #AlexShilman great, that worked. thanks. I was following an old example.